# Updating a Value in a Struct

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain, struct

Hi i am trying to update a value in a struct and i feel like i have tried everything.

i think there is something important i do not know about using solidity structs.

my contracts is defined as:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract Profile {
    struct User {
        string displayName;
        string displayIcon;
    }

    mapping(address => User) public users;
    string name;

    function createUser() public {
        users[msg.sender] = User({
            displayName: "pre-set name",
            displayIcon: "pre-set icon"
        });
    }

    function getDisplayName() public view returns (string) {
        return users[msg.sender].displayName;
    }

    function getDisplayIcon() public view returns (string) {
        return users[msg.sender].displayIcon;
    }

    function setDisplayName(string newDisplayName) public {
        users[msg.sender].displayName = newDisplayName;
    }

    function setDisplayIcon(string newDisplayIcon) public {
        users[msg.sender].displayIcon = newDisplayIcon;
    }

    function getName() public view returns (string) {
        return name;
    }

    function setName(string newName) public {
        name = newName;
    }
}
```

i am calling the setters and getters with:

```
export const createUser = () => ({
    type: PROFILE_CREATE_NEW_USER,
    promise: ({ contracts, coinbase }) => contracts.Profile.createUser({ from: coinbase })
});

export const getDisplayName = () => ({
    type: PROFILE_GET_DISPLAY_NAME,
    promise: ({ contracts }) => contracts.Profile.getDisplayName()
});

export const setDisplayName = payload => ({
    type: PROFILE_SET_DISPLAY_NAME,
    promise: ({ contracts, coinbase }) => contracts.Profile.setDisplayName(payload, { from: coinbase })
});

export const getName = () => ({
    type: 'PROFILE_GET_NAME',
    promise: ({ contracts, coinbase }) => contracts.Profile.getName({ from: coinbase })
});

export const setName = newName => ({
    type: 'PROFILE_SET_NAME',
    promise: ({ contracts, coinbase }) => contracts.Profile.setName(newName, { from: coinbase })
});
```

but when i call these functions, it seems it seems `name` can be get *get* and  *set* correctly, but the value of the struct property (`displayName`) is always an empty string if i try to *get* it.

i added the `createUser` method to see if that would fix the issue, but it still does not work.

i have tried this on Remix and it seems to work.

i'm new to solidity so i think i must be trying to debug this wrong. any help is appreciated.

thanks.

## SOLVED

i have updated my code as suggested by a user below... and SUCCESS! the issue was you ALWAYS have to pass in `{ from: coinbase }` when interacting with structs. the method `getName()` works with and without `{ from: coinbase }`.

Comment: You are not passing `{ from: coinbase }` when you call `getDisplayName()`

Comment: i have tried with and without. i think you should be able perform `read` operations without having to pass in `{ from: coinbase }`. you only need it for when performing `write` operations like `setDisplayName('test', { from: coinbase })`

Comment: Since you use `msg.sender` in the getters it is better to specify `from` it will be used as `msg.sender`. Can you check if the transaction failed with out of gas? You can specify gas like this `{ from: "..", gas: "1000000" }`, using strings can be expensive.

Comment: i have updated my code as you suggested. and SUCCESS! thanks. so it   you ALWAYS have to pass in `{ from: coinbase }` when interacting with structs. the method `getName()` works with and without `{ from: coinbase }`. thank you for your help.

Comment: You have to pass `{ from: "" }` when you use `msg.sender`, `getName()` does work without because it doesn't use `msg.sender`. In any case it should be safe to always specify `{ from }` with the current address.

Comment: thanks. i agree it should always be safe to always pass in `{ from: coinbase }`. do you know if there is a configuration on web3 to do this automatically for all functions? alternatively, i can update my middleware to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have updated my code as suggested by a user below... and SUCCESS! the issue was you ALWAYS have to pass in `{ from: coinbase }` when interacting with structs. the method `getName()` works with and without `{ from: coinbase }`.