# Struct is not saved in mapping for some unknown reason

Tags: mapping, struct

I don't understand why my struct is not saved in mapping. I've tried diffrerent methods of initializing struct I found all over the web and it didn't work on development network (ganache + truffle). What do I wrong?

Original source of the whole project available here: https://github.com/panwaclaw/bxftoken.
Here I leave only part of code with `AccountData` struct and `createAccount()` method.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.7.5;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/AccessControl.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/EnumerableSet.sol";


contract AccountStorage is AccessControl {

    using EnumerableSet for EnumerableSet.AddressSet;
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    struct AccountData {
        address sponsor;
        uint256 balance;
        uint256 selfBuy;
        uint rank;
        uint256 turnover;
        uint256 maxChildTurnover;
        uint256 directBonus;
        uint256 indirectBonus;
        uint256 founderBonus;
        uint256 cryptoRewardBonus;
        uint256 reinvestedAmount;
        uint256 withdrawnAmount;
        int256 distributionBonus;
    }

    EnumerableSet.AddressSet private _accounts;
    mapping (address => AccountData) private _accountsData;

    event AccountCreation(address indexed account, address indexed sponsor);
    

    constructor() {
        address contractAddress = address(this);
        _accountsData[contractAddress].sponsor = address(0);
        _accountsData[contractAddress].balance = 0;
        _accountsData[contractAddress].rank = 0;
        _accountsData[contractAddress].selfBuy = 0;
        _accountsData[contractAddress].turnover = 0;
        _accountsData[contractAddress].maxChildTurnover = 0;
        _accountsData[contractAddress].directBonus = 0;
        _accountsData[contractAddress].indirectBonus = 0;
        _accountsData[contractAddress].founderBonus = 0;
        _accountsData[contractAddress].cryptoRewardBonus = 0;
        _accountsData[contractAddress].distributionBonus = 0;
        _accountsData[contractAddress].reinvestedAmount = 0;
        _accountsData[contractAddress].withdrawnAmount = 0;
    }

   
    function createAccount(address sponsor) public returns(bool) {
        address account = msg.sender;

        if (sponsor == address(0)) {
            sponsor = address(this);
        }
        if (sponsor != address(this)) {
            require(_accounts.contains(sponsor), "AccountStorage: there's no such sponsor, consider joining with existing sponsor account or contract itself");
        }
        if (!hasAccount(account)) {
            _accountsData[account].sponsor = sponsor;
            _accountsData[account].balance = 0;
            _accountsData[account].rank = 0;
            _accountsData[account].selfBuy = 0;
            _accountsData[account].turnover = 0;
            _accountsData[account].maxChildTurnover = 0;
            _accountsData[account].directBonus = 0;
            _accountsData[account].indirectBonus = 0;
            _accountsData[account].founderBonus = 0;
            _accountsData[account].cryptoRewardBonus = 0;
            _accountsData[account].distributionBonus = 0;
            _accountsData[account].reinvestedAmount = 0;
            _accountsData[account].withdrawnAmount = 0;

            _accounts.add(account);

            emit AccountCreation(account, sponsor);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


    function hasAccount(address account) public view returns(bool) {
        return _accounts.contains(account);
    }

}
```

Comment: Why does it not work? Is a test failing? I tried in remix and the contract works as expected. My guess is that the problem is not in the contracts but how they are called.

Comment: @Ismael, The most strange that it passes building tree tests. But I have some other bugs in the contract and I want to debug it with truffle, but it returns very strange results like it doesn't show me anything contained in `_accountsData` mapping. Is that a debugger bug or?

Answer (score 0):

For future generations

[Updating a Value in a Struct](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/42769/updating-a-value-in-a-struct?noredirect=1#comment48487_42769)

**Don't do this if you use SafeMath. This will not work, because that updates field only in `memory`**

```
function increaseBalanceOf(address account, uint256 amount) internal view {
    _accountsData[account].balance.add(amount);
}
```

**Do only this to change struct field in storage!**

```
function increaseBalanceOf(address account, uint256 amount) internal {
    _accountsData[account].balance = _accountsData[account].balance.add(amount);
}
```